# Need SSRS matrix to show more than 400k records

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing the problem in SSRS Matrix report where I need to show more than 400,000 records from the dataset. However I keep getting `system out of memory` errors.

Is it possible?

Comment: Wow never needed that many in ssrs. I'd  like to know the answer though.

Comment: This is *impossible to answer* for us, because it will depend heavily on all factors involved (about which you haven't told us anything). You can easily do the basic experiment yourself (i.e. generate that result set and *try it*), or just even try it with your own result set.

Comment: @Jeroen - If its so easy why can't you help out instead of putting this question down? Obviously its hard otherwise you'd help to answer it like suggesting types of factors they  haven't.

Comment: @glh I meant no offense, merely to indicate that the question showed no research. It helps if the OP [tells us what (s)he's tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com): showing that you've *tried* to help yourself makes it more convenient and attractive for others to invest (their own free) time in a question (see also [this great checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/162730)). In addition, the question is imho [unanswerable](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) in its *current* form, which is why I've voted to close.

Comment: Even though i generated a report (i.e more than 400000)and it shows error like system out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys this issue has been resolved,and just increase the RAM size to i.e 4Gb depending on your need in your R2 server machine.