# Out of memory exeception for straightforward report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to run an SSRS report. It's a straightforward report, just to render data from a table which has around 80K records.

No aggregation or data processing is done in report. There are around 50 columns along with 19 report parameters. I just have to display those 50 columns in report (no pivot).

Usually it takes around 5 minutes to render this report on our development server (off peak hours). Same is the case with our production server, but there users are getting "Out of memory" exceptions a lot, and also report parameter criteria are not utilized (that's the complaints I get from users).

I'm able to filter the criteria locally without any problem although it takes long time to render.

1. Why does it take such a long time to render the report, even though the report is straightforward?
2. The report runs fine when I hit F5 on VS 2008 but from time to time I get out of memory exceptions when I hit the "Preview" tab.
3. Some of the column's name(s) have a "#" character. If I include such columns in the report an "out of memory exception" is thrown (especially in Preview mode). Is there truth to this: doesn't SSRS like column names with "#"? E.g. my column name was "KLN#".
4. I have created a nonclustered index on the table but that didn't help me much.
5. Whats the difference between running the report in Preview mode vs hitting F5 on VS 2008? It's fine when I hit F5 even though it takes 5 minutes, but Preview mode has the problem.

There isn't much room for redesign (since it's a straight forward report), perhaps only can I remove of the report parameters.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: IIRC pressing F5 in VS executes standalone preview - in a separate process. When using Preview tab in VS, report is processed within VS process. Check memory usage of VS when previewing.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the already posted answers and regarding the problems with the preview in the Report Designer or Report Manager there is another possible solution: avoid too much data on the first report page!

It can be done by pagination into small record amounts, i.e. by custom groups with page breaks or sometimes automatically (see the answer of done_merson) or by adding a simple cover page.
These solutions are especially helpfull in the development phase and if you plan to render the report results to Excel or PDF anyway.

I had a similar case with out of memory exceptions and never returning reports with a simple report and its dataset containing about 70k records.
The query was executed in about 1-2 minutes, but neither the Report Designer nor our development SSRS 2008R2 Server (Report Manager) could show the resulting report preview. Finally I suspected the HTML preview being the bottleneck and avoided it by adding a cover page with a simple textbox. The next report execution took about 2 minutes and successfully showed the HTML preview with the cover page. Rendering the complete result to Excel only took another 30 seconds.

Hopefully this will help others, since this page is still one of the top posts if you search for SSRS out of memory exceptions.

Comment: It works great! OMG, what a trick! Thanks a lot! Finally I got my issue solved!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it take such a long time to render...?
>   I have created a Nonclustered index on the table but that didn't help me much.

Because (AFAIK) SSRS will construct an in-memory model of the report before rendering. Know that SSRS will take three steps in creating a report:

1. Retrieve the data.
2. Create an internal model by combining the report and the data.
3. Render the report to the appropriate format (preview, html, xls, etc)

You can check the [ExecutionLog2 View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/05/executionlog2-view.aspx) to see how much time each step takes. Step 1 is probably already reasonably fast (seconds), so the added Index is not tackling the bottle neck. Probably step 2 and 3 are taking a lot of time, and require a lot of RAM.

> SSRS doesn't like column names with #?? my column name was KLN#.

As far as I know this shouldn't be a problem. Removing that column more likely was *just enough* to make the report runnable again.

> There isn't much to redesign (since its a straight forward report) such as except i can remove of the report parameters.

SSRS is just not the right tool for this. As such, there is no real "solution" for your problem, only alternatives and workarounds.

**Workarounds:**

- As @glh mentioned in his answer, making more RAM available for SSRS may "help".
- Requiring the user to filter the data with a parameter (i.e. don't allow the user to select *all* those rows, only the ones he needs).
- Schedule the report at a quiet moment (when there's enough RAM available) and [cache the report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx).

**Alternatives:**

- Create a small custom app that reads from the database and outputs an Excel.
- Use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), which (I thought) is better suited for this kind of task (data transformation and migration).
- Rethink your setup. You haven't mentioned the context of your report, but perhaps you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps your users want the entire report but only need a few key rows, or perhaps they only use it as a backup mechanism (for which there's better alternatives), or...

Comment: ...i think you left out the kitchen sink... ;) i like your answer it definatly shows more investigation will be needed :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase you ram, see this post for a similar error:

[Need SSRS matrix to show more than 400k records](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14169095/1685810)

Comment: Increasing RAM, 1. where you mean on reporting services/sql server or on computer where report is ran. 2. I saw other articles about running large reports on 64 bit so again 64 bit on reporting services/sql server or on computer where report is ran

Comment: I would suspect this to be on the server as this does the processing. To be honest, good luck there could be a number of issues as @Jeroen has stated. I'd love to here your end solution!

Answer (score 0):

We just had a similar situation and set the "Keep together on one page if possible" option in Tablix Properties / General / Page break options to off and it worked fine.